# Android Studio 3.2.1 "My Application Has Stoping" Error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

***Hi, when I run a virtual device on android studio, if I haven't used java code, I don't have error, but if I have java I get the error in the header.***

Logs

```
2018-10-15 16:00:30.055 1266-1302/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
2018-10-15 16:00:30.055 1266-1302/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
2018-10-15 16:00:30.055 1266-1302/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
2018-10-15 16:00:37.959 1688-1688/system_process E/PackageManager: updateAllSharedLibrariesLPw failed: Package com.google.android.dialer requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.dialer.support; failing!
2018-10-15 16:00:38.558 1688-1701/system_process E/AppIdleHistory: Unable to read app idle file for user 0
2018-10-15 16:00:39.006 1688-1688/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Invalid wallpaper data
2018-10-15 16:00:39.006 1688-1688/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Unable to apply new wallpaper
2018-10-15 16:00:39.207 1688-1688/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:39.207 1688-1688/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:39.207 1688-1688/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:39.207 1688-1688/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:39.207 1688-1688/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:39.323 1688-1688/system_process E/InputMethodManagerService: Ignoring updateSystemUiLocked due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
2018-10-15 16:00:39.361 1688-1688/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Invalid wallpaper data
2018-10-15 16:00:39.361 1688-1688/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Unable to apply new wallpaper
2018-10-15 16:00:39.753 1771-1880/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for user_dictionary
2018-10-15 16:00:40.230 1688-1972/system_process E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for call_log
2018-10-15 16:00:42.029 1688-1709/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2018-10-15 16:00:42.029 1688-1709/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:42.030 1688-1709/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:42.032 1688-1709/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2018-10-15 16:00:42.037 1688-1709/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:42.037 1688-1709/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:00:46.084 2277-2447/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:00:51.170 2277-2447/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:00:51.848 2957-2957/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blackerback.myapplication, PID: 2957
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blackerback.myapplication/com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:8)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2018-10-15 16:00:52.724 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:00:55.493 1688-2292/system_process E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
2018-10-15 16:00:55.772 3117-3117/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blackerback.myapplication, PID: 3117
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blackerback.myapplication/com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:8)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2018-10-15 16:00:56.453 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:00:57.572 1688-1770/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2018-10-15 16:01:01.570 1308-1308/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/2118/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2018-10-15 16:01:01.749 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:01:41.820 3270-3270/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:01:41.820 3272-3272/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:01:41.820 3270-3270/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2018-10-15 16:01:41.820 3272-3272/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2018-10-15 16:01:41.917 3088-3236/? E/AppDataSearchHelper: Could not connect to AppDataSearch for onTableChanged, error 8
2018-10-15 16:01:42.078 3152-3152/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: timelysettings
2018-10-15 16:01:44.626 3152-3152/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.playlog.service.START
2018-10-15 16:01:45.013 3152-3152/? E/TimelyPrefService: Primary account is null
2018-10-15 16:01:45.424 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:01:48.226 3555-3555/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:01:48.226 3555-3555/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2018-10-15 16:01:48.611 3568-3568/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blackerback.myapplication, PID: 3568
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blackerback.myapplication/com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.blackerback.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:8)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2018-10-15 16:01:49.023 1311-1311/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1311: eglCreateSyncKHR(1962): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2018-10-15 16:01:49.368 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:01:49.390 1785-1785/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.blackerback.myapplication-1/base.apk
2018-10-15 16:01:49.390 1785-1785/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.blackerback.myapplication-1/base.apk
2018-10-15 16:01:49.390 1785-1785/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.blackerback.myapplication-1/base.apk
2018-10-15 16:01:49.391 1785-1785/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.blackerback.myapplication-1/base.apk
2018-10-15 16:01:54.406 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:01:54.990 3664-3671/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
2018-10-15 16:01:59.908 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:12:51.080 1390-1686/? E/Netd: netlink response contains error (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:12:51.426 1688-1754/system_process E/NetdConnector: NDC Command {64 network destroy 100} took too long (1609ms)
2018-10-15 16:12:51.642 3726-3726/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2018-10-15 16:12:51.642 3726-3726/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2018-10-15 16:12:57.873 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:00.200 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION intent_firewall: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:00.281 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION apn_db: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:00.306 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION tzdata: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:00.340 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION selinux: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:00.347 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION carrier_provisioning_urls: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:02.898 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:04.934 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION intent_firewall: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:04.944 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION apn_db: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:04.948 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION tzdata: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:04.981 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION selinux: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:04.985 3755-3755/? E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION carrier_provisioning_urls: null null
2018-10-15 16:13:07.642 2606-3894/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
2018-10-15 16:13:07.943 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:13.368 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:18.416 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:23.447 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:28.032 3956-4030/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mmsconfig
2018-10-15 16:13:28.414 3956-4030/? E/Babel_SMS: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
2018-10-15 16:13:28.519 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:30.133 1688-1860/system_process E/CryptdConnector: NDC Command {4 cryptfs getpwtype} took too long (1305ms)
2018-10-15 16:13:30.574 2606-4069/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
2018-10-15 16:13:30.649 2606-4072/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
2018-10-15 16:13:33.560 2277-2512/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-15 16:13:36.312 1688-4187/system_process E/BootReceiver: Error reading /data/system/last-header.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/last-header.txt (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:263)
        at
```

MainActivity

```
package com.blackerback.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tvx.setText("eray");
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nexus S API 28 with worked.I did not meet the error in the old version.I've added a simple java code to try it, but I got the error. I would be very glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this line in your `onCreate` method:

```
TextView tvx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
```